# Asp.Net Identity, OpenId implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, asp.net-identity

I need to to authenticate against IBM's SSO which implements the OpenID standard.   Is there any sample code or documentation for implementing a custom OpenID authentication for Asp.Net Identity?

I know that it comes with some built in implementations for Google and Twitter, and all of the samples dealing with Asp.Net Identity and OpenID talk about Google and Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

There's no generic openID provider out of the box today, so you probably have to write your own custom OWIN middleware that talks to IBM's SSO. a similar question is here:

["Generic" OpenID in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493134/generic-openid-in-asp-net-mvc-5)